# Quick way to find a word using a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

My current code is to try to find 2 words "Red Table" in Title:

```
SELECT `id`,`title`,`colors`, `child_value`, `vendor`,`price`, `image1`,`shipping` 
FROM `databasename`.`the_table` WHERE 
`display` = '1' and  (`title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)') 
                and  (`title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)TABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)')
```

The problem is, this is so slow! I even put the status "Index" to the column Title.
I just want to search for multiple words in one (I would prefer in title AND description), but obviously I can't use LIKE because it has to be separated by space or dash or start or end with that word etc.

I tried chat or something like that but phpmyadmin said function doesn't exist.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  MySQL pre-8.0:  `[[:<:]]RED[[:>:]]` is a simplification.  Those codes mean "word boundary", which encompasses space, punctuation, and start/end.

Plan B:  MySQL 8.0:  `\\bRED\\b` is the new phrasing of the Plan A.

Plan C:  `FULLTEXT(title)` with `AND MATCH(title) AGAINST('+RED +TABLE' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Plan D:  If you need specifically "RED TABLE" but not "BLUE TABLE AND A RED CHAIR", then use this technique:

```
  AND MATCH(title) AGAINST('+RED +TABLE' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
  AND LIKE '%RED TABLE%';
```

Note on Plan D:  The fulltext search is very efficient, hences it is done first.  Then other clauses are applied to the few resulting rows.  That is the cost of `LIKE` (or a similar `REGEXP`) is mitigated by having to check many fewer rows.

Note:  We have not discussed "red table" versus "red tables"

By having suitable collation on the column `title`, you can either limit to the same case as the argument of have "Red" = "RED" = "red" = ...

Plan E: (To further fill out the discussion):  `FULLTEXT(title)` with `AND MATCH(title) AGAINST('+"red table" IN BOOLEAN MODE)` should match only "red" and "table" in that order and next to each other.

In general...

- *Use* ENGINE=InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- It is not really practical to set the min word len to 1 or 2.  (3 is the default for InnoDB; and all settings have different names.)
- If your hosting provider does not allow any my.cnf changes, change providers.

Comment: Hi Rick. Thank you so much for your response. Yes my goal is to find words (divided by space, or starting or ending with word).
I tried your method:  "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+RED +TABLE' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`  AND LIKE '%RED TABLE%';".  ------ Only 1 row showed up in results. And I know for sure there are many rows that contains the word "red" AND "table" in the title for example.  I simply want insensitive case word search, but it has to actually be a word, and must contain both red and table. Any suggestions? Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Andrea - Please show me one that worked and one that was not caught by that SQL.

Comment: Hi Rick :) so when I run this query:
" SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+RED +TABLE' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `title` LIKE '%RED TABLE%' " ---------  I get only 1 result and the title for the one found is: "52"H Rima Red Table Lamp". Here is one example of title that does NOT show up in results: "Modern 5-Drawer Spanish Loki End Table Nightstand in Red Wood".  As you can see it does have the word table, and Red :/

Comment: @Andrea - I guess I missed the point.If you want both rows, then use _just_ the `MATCH`, skip the `LIKE`.  Of course, this gets tricky:  "The table was not red"; I suggest it is not practical to worry about.

Comment: k I figured out the problem. It seems Red is only 3 letters so it's ignored. I'm running on gabohost (shared hosting) so I can't change the "ft_min_word_len". Is it possible to somehow put that in the query to not have a minimum length of word? Or change the setting for the table in PHPMYadmin? I'm assuming not, but worth the shot. Can't believe because of your help I was finally able to work, but no there's a darn length minimum :S
PS: I do not have any MY.CNF in my /etc/ webserver

Comment: @Andrea - I added a bit of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can not employ regular index for LIKE or REGEXP. Use [Full Text Search](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php) for this. You can create FULLTEXT index on many columns and search them all in a single expression.

```
CREATE TABLE the_table(
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
title VARCHAR(200), 
description TEXT, 

...

FULLTEXT(title,description)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And write query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE MATCH(title , description )
AGAINST('+RED +TABLE' IN BOOLEAN MODE) -- + means that a word must be present in each row that is returned
```

Read more about usage and options: [MySQL Full text search](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php)

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin. I tried your code, but it provided some rows that do not even have the word "red" in the title and sometimes words like "Tempered" got triggered and showed up in the results. I wanted to search just words, not do %red% for example.  Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!